# CSS issue of user interface on autocomplete when multiple text field

Tags: jquery, html, css, autocomplete

I am having a hard time to fix a problem in CSS.  At the very beginning, I created a page with one text input form with the autocomplete capability.  I tweaked my CSS file to get the rendering I wanted.

Later on, I had to add new text field into that same page.  They are not related to the first one (soo I'm having two form in the same pages).

The problem is that since I added those new text fields the UI is getting messed up.  I think this issue is caused by a bad css attribute.  Let me show you the CSS file and then the html code.

CSS FILE

```
#dynamicsearch {

}

.ui-dynamicsearch {
  z-index: 10000000;
}

#dynamicsearch input[type="text"] {
    background: url(../images/search-dark.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #1B1B1B;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 26px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 65px;
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px #FFFFFF;
    width: 110px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
}

#dynamicsearch input[type="text"]:hover, dynamicsearch input[type="text"]:active{
    width: 160px;
}

.ui-autocomplete {
    background-color:rgba(119,119,119,0.5);
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1 none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.ui-autocomplete.source:hover {
    background: #777;
    width: 210px;
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a{
    text-decoration: none;
    height:14px;
    font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    background: url(../images/folder-dark.png) no-repeat;
    padding-left: 30px;
    display: block;
}
```

And here is the page that call the autocomplete and other text fields.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ASD</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    //autocomplete
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
        source: "db/search.php",
        minLength: 1,
        messages: {
        noResults: '',
        results: function() {}
    }
    });             
});
</script>
<script src="db/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<section id="menu">
    <form action="voir.php" method="post" id="dynamicsearch">
        <input type="text" class='auto' name="dynamicsearch" id="dynamicsearch"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none" />
    </form>
</section>

<article id="state">
    <form method="post" action="db/requete.php">
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <textarea name="probleme" id="textarea" cols="90" rows="5">Enter Text Here</textarea>
    </form>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give us some details on what you mean by "getting messed up"?

Comment: It's like if autosearch is not showing any result or if it does it only show 1 result with no graphic interface as defined in CSS file.  I prepared a picture but since I'm new apparently I need to raise my reputation to be able to post picture hehe.  Sorry about that :)

Comment: Well...if the problem is with the autocomplete dropdown, I'd get rig of all of the formatting and start from scratch. Use the minimum you need to see the list, and then one-by-one add back the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by removing the reference to jquery.js file.

Thanks for your help!